# Open source soft modem that runs on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, open-source, modem

Can anyone recommend an open source soft modem (a software only emulation of a modem card), that runs on Linux?

Preferably, this will be implemented in C/C++

Comment: Is this programming-related?  I'm having a hard time deciding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at [iaxmodem](http://iaxmodem.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I had actually come across iaxmodem in my search, but wanted to see if there were other opinions - or recommendations. +1 for suggesting it though. Incidentally, do you have any experience of using it?

Comment: I've used it with hylafax to send faxes over an asterisk machine (see [fax server tutorial][1]).
But the quality wasn't as good as expected and it doesn't worked reliably. There are suggestions on the net that this combination only works reliably if the iaxmodem is installed on the same machine as the asterisk server. But that wasn't possible in my case.

  [1]: http://www.the-asterisk-book.com/unstable/faxserver-mit-iaxmodem-und-hylafax.html